# What's the maximum number of rows a single SQL Server table can store?

Tags: sql-server

How many rows can we place in a single SQL Server table?

Comment: what about tables in a database. is there any limitations for tables.
can i create any number of tables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no limit, except maybe for your hard drive size.

Have a look at [Estimating the Size of a Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933068(SQL.80).aspx)

and [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server : Rows per table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Tables per database : Limited by number of objects in a database

> Database objects include objects such
>   as tables, views, stored procedures,
>   user-defined functions, triggers,
>   rules, defaults, and constraints. The
>   sum of the number of all objects in a
>   database cannot exceed 2,147,483,647.

Comment: If it's SQL Express, up to 4GB data file.

Comment: ok thank you sir, i have another doubt, what about table is there any limit for creating table.

Comment: Only hardware limitation can restrict it. The sql-server (enterprise) does not restrict it.

Answer (score 1):

```
* System storage limits may preclude the limits specified here. 
* A limit of storage means that the limit is dependent on the amount of storage available.
* A limit of statement means that the limit is dependent on the limit for the maximum length of a statement.
```

But if you want theoretical maximums then the following data maybe useful for you

Maximum number of rows in a non-partitioned table   4294967288
Maximum number of rows in a data partition  4294967288

You can check out IBM's [reference page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzmstlimtabs.htm).

Comment: Is the IBM reference page specific to DB2 or generic?