# What is the maximum number of records I can store in a SQL table?

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the maximum number of rows a single SQL Server table can store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301186/whats-the-maximum-number-of-rows-a-single-sql-server-table-can-store)

What is the maximum number of records I can store in a SQL table?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum database size is 524,272 terabytes.  The Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: should be sufficient for the **vast** majority of cases :-)

Comment: if you need more than that then I want in on the project!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

It says 'Rows per table - limited by available storage'

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a number of things:

1. The schema of the records.
2. The implementation of SQL (there is MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, and others).
3. The particular database type (e.g. MySQL supports InnoDB and several other database formats).
4. The specs of the machine on which it is running (size of the harddisk, for example).

If you are really looking to scale, then you probably want use something like [Google AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) with its [DataStore API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html) built on top of [BigTable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html), or [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), though these won't give you SQL syntax.

MySQL/MariaDB, though, does a pretty good job for smaller data sets, and depending on how scalable you really need to be, it might be the right fit. Or it might make sense to start with MySQL for rapidly getting a product out the door, and then migrating to something more scalable as the need arises.